# Cant start react-native at android via react-native run-android

Tags: reactjs, react-native

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Cant run react-native run-android 
i connect fierbase in this project

```
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'E:\react\fb (2)\fb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 191

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'fb'.
> Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object

  The current character read is 'E' with an int value of 69
  Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object
  line number 1
  index number 0
  Error: Unexpected close tagLine: 31Column: 11Char: >    at error (E:\react\fb (2)\fb\node_modules\sax\lib\sax.js:651:10)    at strictFail (E:\react\fb (2)\fb\node_modules\sax\lib\sax.js:677:7)    at closeTag (E:\react\fb (2)\fb\node_modules\sax\lib\sax.js:871:9)    at SAXParser.write (E:\react\fb (2)\fb\node_modules\sax\lib\sax.js:1436:13)    at new XmlDocument (E:\react\fb (2)\fb\node_modules\xmldoc\lib\xmldoc.js:261:15)    at readManifest (E:\react\fb (2)\fb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\config\readManifest.js:38:10)    at Object.projectConfig (E:\react\fb (2)\fb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\config\index.js:59:46)    at Object.get project [as project] (E:\react\fb (2)\fb\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\config\index.js:134:65)    at E:\react\fb (2)\fb\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\config\config.js:8:452    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
  ^

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Comment: error is very clear. you need to setup Java Runtime Environment and Android SDK as well.

Comment: @MeysamFaghfouri This project was stored through a pen drive which works on original machine. Also my other react native projects works fine with my current environment.

Comment: Have you posted all of the error's text here? usually, it shows more info about error

Comment: Could you try `react-native start`  or `npm start`?

Comment: @hongdevelop 1st i run react-native run-android command

Comment: Have you tried the commands I told you?

Comment: @hongdevelop yeah i try react-native star and npm start but its not working to build My react application